# Updating serialized object Django

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

i would like to ask if someone know where Im doing mistake?

I want to update data in my already serialized object with filled data, i do everything as in documentation in rest framework, but it keeps givim me this errot that my class doesnt have object 'user' or 'firstname', but in data these keys are.

Models

```
class PersonalInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    card_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postal_code = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photo = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)
    debet_card_number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Personal_info'


class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    last_login = models.DateTimeField()
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'User'
```

Serializer class

```
class PersonalInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
user = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
firstname = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
lastname = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
card_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
street = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
postal_code = serializers.IntegerField()
city = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
debet_card_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=16)
created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
last_update = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

def create(self, validated_data):
    return PersonalInfo.objects.create(**validated_data)

def update(self, instance, attrs):
    instance.user = attrs.get('user', instance.user)
    instance.firstname = attrs.get('firstname', instance.firstname)
    instance.lastname = attrs.get('lastname', instance.lastname)
    instance.card_id = attrs.get('card_if', instance.card_id)
    instance.street = attrs.get('street', instance.street)
    instance.postal_code = attrs.get('postal_code', instance.postal_code)
    instance.city = attrs.get('city', instance.city)
    instance.debet_card_number = attrs.get('debet_card_number', instance.debet_card_number)
    instance.created_at = attrs.get('created_at', instance.created_at)
    instance.last_update = datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
    return instance
```

Views. py

```
 personal_info = PersonalInfoSerializer(data=data)
            data['user'] = int(User.objects.get(email=data['email']).id)
            personal_info.is_valid()
            personal_info = PersonalInfoSerializer(personal_info, data=data)
            personal_info.is_valid()
            personal_info.save()
```

and error log wiith .save()

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\cryptoeasy\api\views.py", line 46, in register
    personal_info.save()
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 200, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\cryptoeasy\api\serializers.py", line 48, in update
    instance.user = attrs.get('user', instance.user)
AttributeError: 'PersonalInfoSerializer' object has no attribute 'user
```

'
error log with .data

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 457, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 97, in get_attribute
    instance = getattr(instance, attr)
AttributeError: 'PersonalInfoSerializer' object has no attribute 'firstname'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\cryptoeasy\api\views.py", line 46, in register
    print(personal_info.data)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 548, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 502, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "C:\School\LS_2020_2021\MTAA\app\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 490, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `firstname` on serializer `PersonalInfoSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `PersonalInfoSerializer` instance.
Original exception text was: 'PersonalInfoSerializer' object has no attribute 'firstname'.
```

I want to ask what im doing wrong **with updating serialzer, without updating it works**, Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the `Model` info.

Comment: @ManishShah Yes, of course, i added.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
from .models import PersonalInfo

class PersonalInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     user = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
     firstname = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
     lastname = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
     card_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
     street = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
     postal_code = serializers.IntegerField()
     city = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
     debet_card_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=16)
     created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)
     last_update = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

     def create(self, validated_data):
         return PersonalInfo.objects.create(**validated_data)

     def update(self, instance, attrs):
         instance.user = attrs.get('user', instance.user)
         instance.firstname = attrs.get('firstname', instance.firstname)
         instance.lastname = attrs.get('lastname', instance.lastname)
         instance.card_id = attrs.get('card_if', instance.card_id)
         instance.street = attrs.get('street', instance.street)
         instance.postal_code = attrs.get('postal_code', instance.postal_code)
         instance.city = attrs.get('city', instance.city)
         instance.debet_card_number = attrs.get('debet_card_number', instance.debet_card_number)
         instance.created_at = attrs.get('created_at', instance.created_at)
         instance.last_update = datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
         instance.save()
         return instance

      class Meta:
          model = PersonalInfo
          fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: After i added this class meta, same error occured so no channge :/

Comment: You are doing something wrong in your views.py file, instead why don't you use concrete view classes you can do this in less than 6-7 lines. In your case you are not using any nested serializer so theres no need for explicitly overwrittging the `.create()` and `.update()` method. Use `serializer.ModelSerializer`. and for the views you can define two view classes one for get/create and one for retrieve/update/destroy.

Comment: If you want to get the basics of DRF you can checkout this:- https://github.com/ManishShah120/Learning-DjangoRESTAPI